# Query from list of 2D data points (C++11)

Tags: algorithm, c++11, graph, types

I'm finding it hard to describe (and then search) what I want, so I will try here.

I have a list of 2D data points (time and distance). You could say it's like a vector of pairs. Although the data type doesn't matter, as I'm trying to find the best one now. It is/can be sorted on time.

Here is some example data to help me explain:

[image: Example Data]

So I want to store a fairly large amount of data points like the ones in the spreadsheet above. I then want to be able to query them.

So if I say `get_distance(0.2);` it would return `1.1`. This is quite simple.
Something like a map sounds sensible here to store the data with the time being the key. But then I come to the problem, what happens if the time I am querying isn't in the map like below:

But if I say `get_distance(0.45);`, I want it to average between the two nearest points just like the line on the graph and it would return `2`.

All I have in my head at the minute is to loop through the data point vector find the point that has the closest time less than the time I want and find the point with the closest time above the time I want and average the distances. I don't think this sounds efficient, especially with a large amount of data points (probably up to around 10000, but there is a possibility to have more than this) and I want to do this query fairly often.

If anyone has a nice data type or algorithm that would work for me and could point me in that direction I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STL is the way to go.

If your query time is not in the data, you want the largest that is smaller and the smallest that is larger so you can interpolate.

https://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

https://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/

Note that since your data is already sorted you do not need a map - a vector is fine and saves the time taken to populate the map

Answer (score 0):

You can still achieve this in `O(N log N)` time complexity, `N` being the scale of the data, with a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

You can first query if there is an exact match. Use something like [`std::map::find`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) to acheive this.

If there is no exact match, we should now query for the two keys that are the largest less than, or the least greater than the query (basically find the two keys that "sandwich" the query).

To do this, use [`std::map::lower_bound`](https://std::map::lower_bound) (or [`std::map::upper_bound`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/upper_bound/), as the two are equivalent in this case). Save the iterator that is returned. To find the key greater than the query, simply increment the iterator (if `itr` is the iterator, just do `itr++` and look for the value there).

The `lower_bound` (or `upper_bound`), along with `find` are all in `O(N log N)` and incrementing is `O(log N)`, giving a total time complexity of `O(N log N)`, which should be efficient enough in your case.

Comment: since the data is already sorted a map in not needed.

Comment: @ravenspoint They're the same time complexity.

Comment: Nope.  You have to take account how long it will take to add the data points to the map.  Also the space required to store a duplicate copy of the data.

Comment: @ravenspoint Right, but still the same time *complexity*. And empirically, efficient implementations may not even differ by that much.

Comment: No matter how clever the coder, using a map when a pre-sorted vector is available, will always take longer and require more memory.

Comment: @ravenspoint I'd say, in the most extreme cases, the difference is trivial. They're the exact same time complexity.

Comment: It seems that you are recommending an approach that is always slower and uses more memory because if the coder is extremely clever it will only be slightly slower ( The memory requirement will always be doubled, at least )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246354/discussion-between-ryan-zhang-and-ravenspoint).